# ChangeLog OriginalValue same as CurrentValue on EF Core Update Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a **problem with updating entities in EF Core** and then **logging those changes in a table**. Technologies used are:

- .NET Core 2.2.0
- EF Core 2.2.3

So, I want to get an entity from the database, edit it in front-end and then update it on the backend and save those changes into the database. On top of that, I have a table called `ChangeLogs` where the most important fields are From (mapped from `OldValues`) and To (mapped from `CurrentValues`). Well, those two fields are the same (meaning they have the exact same values, the new values) and the situation goes like this:

1. I get the entity from the database like this

   `_context.Anomalies
        .Include(a => a.Asset)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == anomalyId)`
2. Edit the entity in front-end and then make a PUT request to update it;
3. Update the entity:

   In order for the `Update()` to work, first I have to call this:
   `_context.DetachAllEntities();` Otherwise I get an error saying that an entity with the same Id is already being tracked. Then call `Update()` and `SaveChanges()`:

   `_context.Anomalies.Update(anomaly);
   _context.SaveChanges();`

   The `anomaly` object is the one from the request.
4. For the `ChangeLog` part, I overridden the `SaveChanges()` method, following [this example](https://www.meziantou.net/2017/08/14/entity-framework-core-history-audit-table), and the Old/Original and New/Current values are set like this:

   `auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
   auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;`

   Basically this goes through all entries from `ChangeTracker`, creates an `AuditEntry` and after the `base.SaveChanges()` it will go back and set the EntityId for that AuditEntry because you don't have it before save changes (this is in case you add a new entity, for update nothing happens after save changes).

The Update() method is working, changes are reflected in the database. But the only problem is with `ChangeLogs`, the entry from `ChangeTracker.Entries()` does not know the `OldValues`.

---

I admit that I don't fully understand the tracking system used by EF, but I suppose it should help me updating entities and not create problems. Because I know calling `_context.DetachAllEntities();`is not correct. I tried to use `AsNoTracking()` and drop the `DetachAllEntities()` but the result seems to be the same. I thought about taking the dbEntity, copy each field from request entity to database entity and then `Update(dbEntity)` but that seems like a lot of work to do for basically a small benefit. My `Anomaly` entity has a lot of navigation properties, it would be difficult to create a copy method for it and to maintain it.

The `DetachAllEntities()` is defined like this:

```
public static void DetachAllEntities(this DbContext context)
{
    var entries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
}
```

`DbContext` is set to `Scoped` lifetime, managers as well.

I tried to use the Auditing method from [this tutorial](https://entityframework-plus.net/tutorial-audit) as well, but the result is the same.

I have a concern that the whole Update process is not done right and therefore this problems..

> **UPDATE**
>   I have created a sample project to exemplify this problem. [You can check the source code on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/marian_simonca/ef-core-update/src/master/). The README hase some more info on this

I serialized the objects retrieved from the context.

With Tracking on the LEFT <====> With NO tracking on the RIGHT
[image: With Tracking on the LEFT <====> With NO tracking on the RIGHT]

*Any advice, opinion, new idea, comment is welcomed. Thank you!*

Comment: I think "DetachEntities" is the source of your problem. Detaching will remove the entities from change tracking and therefore the Original Value and ChangedValues wont change..

Comment: Ok. But I tried without it and I get an error when I call Update(): 'Entity is already being tracked'. So, without it I can't even save my changes

Comment: Its worth taking a look at this library to see how its been done - or even just bring in a reference to it and use it directly - it'll probably save you some headache: https://github.com/Arch/AutoHistory/ - To give you a more specific answer to your particular problem - we'd probably need to see more code, in context to understand what is going on

Comment: I will take a look at that library. Thanks a lot! Also, I will try to provide a small project reproducing the problem after work

Comment: Question has been updated with a sample project to exemplify the problem

Comment: Is there a reason you need to call update?  When performing changes with EF, all you have to do is change the fields on your entity and call savechanges.  Update isn't needed to perform an update.

Comment: I just removed the `Update()` call but now the entity is not updated. `.AsNoTracking()` is commented

Comment: Remove detach too :)

Comment: Removed, still not working.. :(

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I think your problem is here. Because the two objects exist in different contexts, it is fundamentally a different object. If you change your code so that you retrieve the entity from the database, update its values, then use that object to pass to the SaveChangesAndAudit() method. You will get the result you are expecting. I have adjusted the code in the attached screenshot. You will also come up against a fundamental problem that most developers find, and that is mapping objects - tools like Automapper make your life easier with this sort of thing - so if your entities are big, its worth taking a look at that to help ;-)

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: Basically, I have no chance but to map the webEntity with dbEntity field-by-field? This is so discouraging.. I know about auto mapper, but I really thought there might be a better solution

Comment: You will need to because EF wont be able to track the changes. It needs to have the object in its context so that it can capture the Set() methods on its properties and record whats changed. Its only at the point that those values are changed, that it is tracked. Thats just fundamentally how it works unfortunately

Comment: I know it might not sound like great news - but it is the correct answer for this question :-s

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert, will try your solution and use automapper, if it ends well I owe you a big one :)

Answer (score 1):

When using EF, the entities are created/populated with 'tracking' information that links the entity back to the context (and other things).

In order to update an entity, all you need to do is query for an entity from the context, change the values and then call savechanges.  There is no need to detach the entities (unless you have a specific reason for doing so).

> The following example is all that you need to update an entity.

EX:

```
    var anomly = _context.Anomalies
     .Include(a => a.Asset)
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == anomalyId);

    anomly.Description = "I have changed the description";

    _context.SaveChanges();
```

**EDIT**

> If you close the context or detach, then you need to query for the  the entity and update it with the new values before calling savchanges.

EX:

```
var anomly = _context.Anomalies
 .Include(a => a.Asset)
 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == anomalyId);

anomly.Description = "I have changed the description";

_context.Dispose();

_context = new DBContext();

var databaseAnomoly = _context.Anomalies
 .Include(a => a.Asset)
 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == anomaly.Id);

//Update fields
databaseAnomoly.Description = anomly.Description;

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I changed my code to `_context.Attach(anomaly); _context.SaveChanges();`. Still the same error. From what I understand, it tries to go through all properties of anomaly and attach them, but if a navigation property is added and later on an entity with the same ID is found, the error pops up. Even if first entity added is `Anomaly.Asset` and the second one is found in `Anomaly.Inspection.Asset` (as an example)

Comment: Edited and removed the attach stuff, as that didn't do what I was thinking :)

Comment: Ok, now I understand exactly what you wanted to say. But one problem here, my entity is big, like a lot of properties. It would be a nightmare to copy field-by-field..  I thought about since the beginning but it does not seem like a good solution, more like a work-around

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with having a ton of fields and resolved it by overloading the + operator.  So now we just do databaseAnomoly += anomly.  You still end up writing all the code to copy field to field, but you only do it once.

Comment: @Simonca - EF will do what you want it to do, its your understanding of it thats a little off. Theres too many variables (pardon the pun) to give a proper answer - are you able to post your actual code as it is so we can help better?

Comment: Yes @Robert, I admit my understanding might be a bit off, I am still learning as I work. I uploaded a sample code here: https://bitbucket.org/marian_simonca/ef-core-update/src/master/ (same link as on the Updated question)

Comment: Ah ok.. I’ll take a look at the code and post my answer below.. I’m sure it’s something simple

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe is that your entity does not originally comes from the database, so DbContext does not know the old value of the properties. So this can be simply fixed by pulling the entity from the database and updating it, either manually like in the sample code below or using Automapper.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEditAsync(int id, Product value)  
{  
    var product = dbContext.Products.Find(p => p.Id == id);  

    //Map exisiting product with new values (idealy with Automapper)  
    product.Name = value.Name;  
    product.Price = value.Price;  
    product.Description = value.Description;  

    dbContext.Update(product);  
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();  
}
```